# StoredProcedureItemReader Multithreaded

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

Use Case:

I have created A, B, C annotation based Spring Batch Job.

All has single step.

I am using `StoredProcedureItemReader` to read data from the database, `Flatfilewriter` to write data.

I am using Spring Integration where I have a StepSplitter, ServiceActivator and Aggregator.

In Service Activator I am doing `jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);`

Expectation is same jobs should run with different parameter parallel.
I configure both job and step with `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.

Suppose 6 jobs are running 2A,3B,C with different parameters. Only 4 files are generating.

I am getting exception:

> Stream is already initialized.  Close before re-opening.
>   Reader must be open before it can be read.

Comment: Please add more information. For example, how do you determine the target file name? Is it possible 2 jobs might be writing to the same file? Have you confirmed there are 6 distinct job instances in the `BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE` table?

Comment: We are not using BATCH_JOB_INSTACE table.But I checked by putting a break point at aggregate that all are having different instance. Thx for the quick reply.

Comment: How? ...do you just use an in-memory job repository?

Comment: Yes.We don't need to restart the jobs.So It has not implemented.

Comment: Just to make correction.I am getting same job instance id (3) but job execution id is different.Which is expected .Because I have only 3 jobs but 6 different sets of Parameters.

Comment: You should make the job parameters "identifying". That will create a new instance per unique set of parameters.

Comment: My Jobs are created at starting of the application.Then through jobLuncher.run I am passing the job instance and parameters.All job instances are coming as same.

Comment: In Service Activator we are lunching our job.

Comment: @Dean: my job  names are the store procedure names and all has different set of IN and OUT parameter. Starting of my application I am creating those jobs.In Activator I am passing the IN values as Job parameters and right after that It calls jobluncher.run(job,parameters);

Comment: Please post your context file for more detail and check that your writer is in `scope="step"` if you are running multiple job executions in the same job context

Comment: @Michael Minella on one of your answer (Error in Spring batch with multi-threading)you suggested that StoreprocedureItem reader in not thread safe.But if the scope is step for a reader and job parameters are different for a job then is there any issue with multithreaded request or still we need to make our own itemreader implementation.